# Rails check_box inside fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested form

```
- f.object.buttons.build if f.object.buttons.blank?
- f.object.buttons.each do |button|
  = f.fields_for :buttons, button, index: nil do |button|
    .control-group
      = button.label :url, 'Url'
      = button.text_field :url, {type: 'url'}

    .control-group
      = button.label :active, 'Active'
      = button.check_box :active

    # ...
```

When I check check_box and save this form, something weird happened: in the params hash I can see, that instead of one button with checked params 'active' form sends two buttons:

```
..., "buttons"=>[{"label"=>"site", "url"=>"http://example.com", "active"=>"0"}, {"active"=>"1"}]}
```

Comment: You have two elements for button defined in your view. `text_field` with name `url` and `check_box` with name `active`. Why are you expecting just one ?

Comment: @Vimsha, I don't expect one parameter. I expect that if checkbox "active" is checked for the specific button, then this param should be placed inside nested params like this: `"buttons"=>[{"label"=>"site", "url"=>"http://example.com", "active"=>"1"}]}`, not like this: `"buttons"=>[{"label"=>"site", "url"=>"http://example.com", "active"=>"0"}, {"active"=>"1"}]}`.

And I can't understand why this is happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two variables named `button` in your fields_for scope